# Default Message Boxes

Tags: windows

The title might be pretty stupid but there's just two questions that I need answered and I don't know what title to set.

Basically I want to know what is the program or the thing responsible for the windows pop-ups like open as administrator pop ups or the windows not genuine pop up, is there a program maybe in system32 that takes care of these things or how does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check out this link for Windows not genuine type - pop ups:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee330740(v=vs.85).aspx

It's called `notification area` and the pop ups are called `balloon notifications`.

Edit: You might also want to check out `MessageBox` API.